# Chrome/FireFox not Displaying Updates to Offline Page

Tags: html, offlineapps

I am working with the HTML5 applicationCache API and I am having a problem seeing updates to the cached page. I’m taking care of the basics – making changes to the manifest file, making sure the manifest isn't caching on the client, and reloading the page after the new version of the cached page is downloaded (after onupdateready event).

I know the applicationCache API is supported in Chrome and FireFox, but I can only see the desired behavior (changes in cached page after updating manifest) in Opera and Safari.

Therefore, how do I ensure that I can see the latest cached version of the page in Chrome and FireFox?

Here's my HTML/JavaScript (index.htm):

```
<!doctype html>
<html manifest="manifest.aspx">
<head>
    <title>Log</title>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {

            if (window.applicationCache) {
                var log = document.getElementById("log");

                function logEvent(msg) {
                    log.innerHTML += "<li>" + msg + "</li>";
                }

                window.applicationCache.onchecking = function (e) {
                    logEvent("checking cache");
                }

                window.applicationCache.oncached = function (e) {
                    logEvent("cached");
                }

                window.applicationCache.onupdateready = function (e) {
                    logEvent("update ready");
                    logEvent("swapping cache");
                    applicationCache.swapCache();
                }

                window.applicationCache.onnoupdate = function (e) {
                    logEvent("no update");
                }

                window.applicationCache.onobsolete = function (e) {
                    logEvent("obsolete");
                }

                window.applicationCache.ondownloading = function (e) {
                    logEvent("downloading");
                }

                window.applicationCache.onerror = function (e) {
                    logEvent("error");
                }

                logEvent("window load");
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Message Logger 15</h1>

        <div id="eventLogContainer">
            <h2>Event Log</h2>
            <ul id="log"></ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my manifest (manifest.aspx):

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# version fifteen

CACHE:
index.htm
```

My manifest is a ASPX file, but the **Content-Type** is set to `text/cache-manifest` and **Encoding** is set to `utf-8`.

Comment: Here's a person with a similar problem: [swapCache function in manifest does not work all the time?](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=0b40036f9144fe1d&hl=en)

Comment: I'm confused as to why the person in that link is swapping the cache programmatically; why not let the browser do it as intended? I just use the events for testing purposes.

Comment: It looks like he's just forcing an update programmatically while I'm just refreshing the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although updating the cache manifest will cause the browser to check for new files, whether or not those files are fetched from the server or from the local browser cache is determined by regular caching rules.  Thus if your browser is configured to only look for a new version of any file once per day, or there are future expires headers being served with the files listed in your cache manifest, those files will not be updated when you update the manifest file (unless you empty the browser cache, or do a CTRL + F5).

So in short: check what headers `index.htm` is getting served with.

Comment: Thanks, Robert! I was able to configure the page to send the right HTTP headers telling the browser not to do 'normal' caching. The only hang up I have now is that for some reason the only way I can get the headers to render correctly is by setting `this.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);` in an ASPX page. When I set the META tags manually in a HTML page, the cache control is still coming back as `public`, but I'll start a new thread for that question. Thanks again!

Comment: After a little more research I am going to abandon trying to rely just on META tags to change the headers. It looks like the most reliable way to do it is to set the values I need on the server.

Comment: @CraigShoemaker Sorry - I didn't realize you were trying to do it with meta tags.  Yes, that is unlikely to work, configuring the server to send the correct headers is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

I have your example working in Chrome and Safari no problem, and after a couple of refreshes in Firefox 4 (I find FF's appcache implementation to be somewhat 'laggy' compared with the others).

Presumably you're not getting any error in your logging code, it's just not showing the change on page refresh after modifying the HTML and the manifest file, is that right?

Things to check:

1. Is the HTML well-formed? Screwed-up HTML will lead to errors (ensure the page is HTML5 too).
2. Do you reference a favicon in your mark-up? If not, do so (even if it's an empty link) -- webkit will report an error otherwise (don't know about FF)
3. When you change your cache manifest, are you definitely changing its file size each time, i.e. adding / removing comments so that line lengths change?
4. Test that the cache really is served with the correct content-type. In UN*X you can do this from a terminal session like so: `curl -I http://your-domain/path/to/cache-manifest.manifest` Alternatively use Firebug or similar to examine the headers when serving up your cache file
5. Check that the path to the cache file is correct in all HTML pages referencing it

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I updated the post to show all the markup and manifest file. I tried adding a favicon and that had no effect. Regarding changing the manifest, yes I am changing the revision comment each time.

Comment: I copied your manifest file and mark-up, and it failed for me too, logging an error. I had the same relative path to the manifest file as you, but my manifest was at the same level as the test html page. When I removed the backslash from the manifest line it all worked. I appreciate that there is probably more to it than that for you, but this is what fixed it for me!

Comment: Thanks, Ben :) I removed the slash and the problem still persists - I just can't think of what else I am missing...

Comment: I updated your post with numbers for easier reference. For #4 I have tested in Chrome (F12) and Firebug to verify it's serving the right mime type. I also verified paths (#5) and still no avail. Thank you kindly for your suggestions though!